# Open the "open"-dialogbox from cmd

Tags: file, cmd

I want to know if I can open the "open"-dialogbox from the cmd, so I can use that to choose the right file to open.
(I already know how to open the file directly from the cmd, but thats not what I interested in)

At the moment I'm doing a project where i use a program (e.g. program.exe). This program needs a modelfile (e.g. modelfile.mod).
I execute the program in the CMD by writing: program.exe modelfile.mod, and it work.
I have many modelfiles with different names, but the program file always has the same name. Instead of writing in the CMD every time I need to execute the program I would like to create a batch where I can choose the modfile I like to execute whereafter it executes the program with the chosen modfile as input.

Therefore I need to know how to open the "open"-dialogbox from the cmd, and also how to get the name of the chosen file for use in execution of the program.

Comment: cmd has a command line interface, there are no dialog boxes.

Comment: I do agree that the CMD has a command line interface, but by using e.g. "start ." or "explorer ." a dialogbox can be show where all files can be shown. But these functions can only open files, where I at the moment want to know what file there have been selected in the dialogbox.

Comment: "start ." translates to "start <currentdir>" and the default-program for an directory is to start the explorer (as "start www.google.com"  would start your default browser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got PowerShell installed, you can do something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set ps_cmd=powershell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms|Out-Null;$f=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;$f.Filter='Model Files (*.mod)|*.mod|All files (*.*)|*.*';$f.showHelp=$true;$f.ShowDialog()|Out-Null;$f.FileName"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%ps_cmd%') do set "filename=%%I"

if defined filename (
    echo You chose %filename%
) else (
    echo You didn't choose squat!
)

goto :EOF
```

Or if you want to break down the powershell cmdlets for easier maintenance:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ps=Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms | Out-Null;"
set "ps=%ps% $f=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;"
set "ps=%ps% $f.Filter='Model Files (*.mod)|*.mod|All files (*.*)|*.*';"
set "ps=%ps% $f.showHelp=$true;"
set "ps=%ps% $f.ShowDialog() | Out-Null;"
set "ps=%ps% $f.FileName"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell "%ps%"') do set "filename=%%I"

if defined filename (
    echo You chose %filename%
) else (
    echo You didn't choose squat!
)

goto :EOF
```

(PowerShell command mercilessly leeched from the [Just Tinkering Blog](http://justtinkering.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/use-file-open-dialog-in-powershell/).)  See the [OpenFileDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) documentation for other properties you can set, such as `Title` and `InitialDirectory`.