# batch - differentiating between a file and a path?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set /p UserInput= What file would you like to hide?

cd %UserInput%
```

So I want to make a batch file that when run asks the user for a file, which it will hide in a maze of random folders. Let me explain.

Let's say I type `C:\Program Files\Steam\butts.exe`

It'd make a new directory in `C:\Program Files\Steam`

This is where I'm stuck. How do I have it find `C:\Program Files\Steam` from `C:\Program Files\Steam\butts.exe`?

Comment: semi-related: You should add `setlocal` to your script to encapsulate the variables.  This will keep you from junking up your environment with a bunch of variables that ought to be limited to the scope of this one batch script.  Also, if a user does `Ctrl`+`C` to break out of the script, having a `setlocal` will return the console back to the starting directory.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15659309/1683264) for more information.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in using a [gui file chooser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/) to capture the user's file choice.

Answer (score 2):

Hah!  The quickest and hacksiest way would be just to add a `\..` to the end.  For instance, on my desktop I have a file called `weather.xml`.  If I do this:

```
dir c:\users\me\Desktop\weather.xml\..
```

... I end up with a directory listing of my Desktop.  :)

So you can accomplish what you need with

```
cd %UserInput%\..
```

Otherwise, you could pass the path to a `for` loop or `call :label` to a subroutine to end up with `%%~dpX`.  See the last couple of pages of `help for` and `help call` for details.

---

If you want to be even hacksier, instead of requiring the user to enter the `path\to\file` to set `%UserInput%`, you can use `powershell` to launch a `File... Open` sort of file chooser.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15658703/1683264) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal 
for %%i in ("C:\Program Files\Steam\butts.exe") do set "steampath=%%~dpi"
:: remove last backslash
echo %steampath:~0,-1%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this batch

```
@echo off
set /p UserInput=What file would you like to hide?
for %%i in ("%UserInput%") do set path="%%~dpi"
cd %path%
```

Comment: Using a `for` loop and `%%~dpI` is appropriate, but using "path" as the variable name is not a good idea.  Add a `setlocal` below `@echo off` to avoid messing up the system `%PATH%` variable.  Even if you choose to rename `path` to something else, `setlocal` is still good practice to keep from junking up your environment variables.